# Inserting rows through SQirreL SQL Client for Apache Phoenix

Tags: apache-phoenix, squirrel-sql

Using:

- SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.7
- Phoenix Thin Drive

Database us_population is already created by running the following query in SQuirreL SQL Client

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS us_population (
      state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
      city VARCHAR NOT NULL,
      population BIGINT
      CONSTRAINT my_pk PRIMARY KEY (state, city));
```

When I tried inserting 1 row

```
UPSERT INTO US_POPULATION (STATE,CITY,POPULATION) VALUES ('NY','New York',8143197);
```

The following message is outputed

```
Query 1 of 1, Rows read: 0, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 0.106, SQL query: 0.106, Reading results: 0
```

When I tried to retrieve all the records, there are zero rows found.

```
SELECT * FROM US_POPULATION
```

Result

```
Rows: 0
```

How can I insert 1 row?

I am new to SQuirreL SQL and Apache Phoenix by the way.

Comment: I don't understand why. But when I restart my SQuirreL, it is already working.